# Line spacing for different FontSizes in WPF RichtextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I want my RichtextBox to enable line spacing chosen by user (multiplier of 1, 1.5 or 2). I tried to programatically change LineHeight of paragraphs, setting it to FontSize*multiplier. That works fine, but it can't be used for different fontSizes in the same paragraph, because then I have to choose one of the sizes for the calculation of LineHeight. 
I would like to have it similar like in WordPad or OpenOffice, where the actual LineHeight is calculated for each line using the biggest fontSize used on the line.
Is there any possibility to change the LineHeight for lines or to tell the RichTextBox to just use the multiplier? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the **LineStackingStrategy**="MaxHeight" for the Blocks. See this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.linestackingstrategy.aspx

Comment: That doesn't help, because I need to change the line spacing - and using LineHeight for it the MaxHeight strategy would set my lineHeight to the height of the biggest fontSize. And I need it multiplied by the line spacing.